# change the image of my music button when it's on and off

Tags: css, html

I have an button on my page witch switch music on an off I have styled it with css to it appear with an custom image... can I change the image of this button when it's on and off
thanks

this is my audio code

```
<audio id="myAudio"
                    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4"
         type='audio/mp4'>
                    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
         type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
                    Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
                    </audio>
                    <script>
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is my html button

```
<button class="soundButton" type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause()"></button>
```

and this is my css style

```
.soundButton{
    width:23px;
    height:18px;
    border:none;
    background:url(../../images/speakerIcon.png);
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: You should use a content image, not a background image. One reason to this is that only content images can have text fallbacks (`alt` attributes). Changing the content image when the play is started appears to be a simple thing to do. In any case, please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
function aud_play_pause(d) {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
     d.className = 'soundButton';
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
     d.className = 'soundOffButton';
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="soundButton" type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause(this)"></button>
```

CSS:

```
.soundOffButton{
    width:23px;
    height:18px;
    border:none;
    background:url(../../images/speakerIconOFF.png);
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your javascript like this:

```
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  var myButton = document.getElementsByClassName("soundButton");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
    myButton.style.background="background-image: url('image/speakerIconPause.png')";
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
    myButton.style.background="background-image: url('image/speakerIconPlay.png')";
  }
}
```

off course you need two background images:

- speakerIconPause.png
- speakerIconPlay.png

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<audio id="myAudio">
                    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4"
         type='audio/mp4'>
                    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
         type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
                    Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
                    </audio>
                    <script>
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('soundButton')[0];
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
    button.classList.remove('paused');
    button.classList.add('playing');
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
    button.classList.remove('playing');
    button.classList.add('paused');
  }
}
</script>
```

with these styles:

```
.soundButton{
    width:23px;
    height:18px;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.soundButton.playing {
    background:url(../../images/speakerIcon.png);
}
.soundButton.paused {
    background:url(../../images/pausedIcon.png);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just have two styles for the different look that you want to achieve. Then use JQuery to use the  right on.

eg

```
$('#button).removeClass('off').addClass('on')
```

and vice-verse to do the apposite

Comment: He's not using jquery.

Comment: He could. It is a simple solution to the problem